# Netty equivalent to getOutputStream()

Tags: netty

I have written a server for uploading files in Netty but I do no succeed in realizing the equivalent of the `response.getOutputStream()` in java.
How can I do, knowing that I have at disposal a `ChannelHandlerContext` object and a `DefaultFullHttpRequest` object.

Here is my code:

```java
@Override
public void channelRead0(final ChannelHandlerContext chctx, final DefaultFullHttpRequest object)
    throws Exception {
    // Retrieving the content
    ByteBuf data = object.content();

    if (HttpMethod.POST.equals(object.getMethod())) {
        /*  while (data.isReadable()) {
                output.write(data.readByte());
        }*/
        int dataLen = data.readableBytes();
        ByteBuffer nioData;
        if (data.nioBufferCount() != -1) {
            nioData = data.nioBuffer();
        } else {
            nioData = ByteBuffer.allocate(dataLen);
            data.getBytes(data.readerIndex(), nioData);
            nioData.flip(); // The inputstream
        }
        /*  FileChannel chan =  outputStream.getChannel();
            chan.write(data);
            chan.transferFrom(chctx.write,0,dataLen);*/
        //  chctx.write(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method `readBytes(OutputStream out,int length)` of ByteBuf to write data summited by the http request to a FileOutputStream:

```
...
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("someFile");
nioData.readBytes(out,  nioData.readableBytes());
...
```